# Trying to remove/hide fields in custom tab in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to figure out a way (if possible) to remove or hide certain fields in a custom tab. The custom tab is labeled "Rotator" and it holds images that can be used for a rotating banner on a page. The home page banner is a little different in that it has 2 extra fields that aren't needed on the subpages: BackgroundImage and Body(which is meant to hold a variety of text). I want to make things simple for the content manager, so I want to hide these fields on the subpages.

I am aware of removeFieldFromTab and how it works, and I was thinking of using it on the Page.php file (since that is basically the main template for all page types in my SilverStripe file):

```
  public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $gridFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();

    $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldBulkImageUpload());
    $gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));

    $gridFieldConfig->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
        // field from drawer class => label in UI
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'Title' => 'Title',
        'Thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail',
        'InternalURL.Link' => 'Internal URL',
    ));

    $gridfield = new GridField(
        "Rotator",
        "Rotator",
        $this->Rotator()->sort("SortOrder"),
        $gridFieldConfig
    );

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Rotator', $gridfield);
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField("H1"), "Content");
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField("Subheader"), "Content");
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('PageTitle', 'Page Title'), 'MetaDescription');
    $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Rotator', 'Body');
    $fields->removeFieldFromTab('Root.Rotator', 'BackgroundImage');
    return $fields;
}
```

Here is the code for the Rotator class:

```
<?php

class RotatorImage extends DataObject {

    public static $db = array(
        'SortOrder' => 'Int',
        'Header' => 'varchar',
        'Body' => 'HTMLText',
    );

    // One-to-one relationship with gallery page
    public static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
        'BackgroundImage' => 'Image',
        'Page' => 'Page',
        'InternalURL' => 'SiteTree',
    );

    // tidy up the CMS by not showing these fields
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","PageID");
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","SortOrder");
        return $fields;
    }

    // Tell the datagrid what fields to show in the table
    public static $summary_fields = array(
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'Title' => 'Title',
        'Thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail',
        'InternalURLID' => 'Internal URL',
    );

    // this function creates the thumnail for the summary fields to use
    public function getThumbnail() {
        return $this->Image()->CMSThumbnail();
    }

    public function canEdit() {
        return true;
    }

    public function canDelete() {
        return true;
    }

    public function canCreate(){
        return true;
    }

    public function canPublish(){
        return true;
    }

    public function canView(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

However this does not work, and I am sure that I have the fields names correct. I tried 'Root.Rotator.Main' and 'Root.Rotator.Content' just to see what would happen and those also did not work. What am I missing? Is it possible to hide fields on a custom tab this way, or do I need to try something else?

Comment: where are your fields "Body" and "BackgroundImage" added? In a DataExtension? You might also check the class of the page when adding it...

Comment: The "Body" and "BackgroundImage" fields are located in a class. I posted the code for it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you want to hide the fields in the gridfield detail form? that cannot be done in your pages `getCMSFields()`, as the grid is responsible for generating the detail form. Two possible solutions:

1) tell the grid to hide that fields with a custom component. I dunno how to do it

2) tell your Rotator class to show the fields ONLY if the related page is a homepage:

```
public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    //...other stuff....

    $isOnHomePage = ($this->Page() && $this->Page()->ClassName == 'HomePage'); //put in your own classname or conditions

    if(!$isOnHomePage) {
        //remove the fields if you're not on the HomePage
        $fields->removeByName('Body');
        //we need to suffix with "ID" when we have a has_one relation!
        $fields->removeByName('BackGroundImageID'); 
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work...

```
$fields->removeByName('FieldName');
```